# Is this derivation of the Boltzmann distribution any good?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I tried to come up with a derivation of the distribution during a highschool class, and this is what I found. I know the explanation below isn't rigorous, but I was wondering if anyone had any commentary (I'm mostly clueless about thermodynamics), or if they know any similar or simpler derivations!

Edit: I'm familiar with the typical ones, but was partly hoping to find one that uses high-school accessible maths and was mostly self contained (e.g. avoiding non-central results).

"For notation, I was trying to find some $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ that follows the constraints (which represents the number of particles in a given energy state:

$\sum f(n)=N$

$\sum n \cdot f(n)=E$

And maximises the corresponding number of states $Q = \frac{N!}{f(0)!f(1)!f(2)!...}$

So, given some function that meets the constraints, you can consider the values of $f(a)$, $f(a-x)$, and $f(a+x)$ for some $a$ and $x$.

If you decrease $f(a)$ by $2$, and increase $f(a-x)$ and $f(a+x)$ by $1$ each, you get a new function which also matches the constraints (I hope it's apparent how) with $\frac{Q_{\text{updated}}}{Q_0}=\frac{f(a)(f(a)-1)}{(f(a+x)+1)(f(a-x)+1)}$. If you do the same thing in the other direction,
it's $\frac{Q_{\text{updated}}}{Q_0}=\frac{(f(a+x)-1)(f(a-x)-1)}{(f(a)+1)(f(a)+2)}$.

When the values of the function are sufficiently large, these are roughly equal to $\frac{f(a)^2}{f(a+x)f(a-x)}$ and $\frac{f(a+x)f(a-x)}{f(a)^2}$.

Either they're both equal to $1$, or one is bigger. If one is bigger, the corresponding updated distribution has more corresponding states, so the distribution that maximises Q has to have $f(a)^2=f(a-x)f(a+x)$.

If you take $f$ as a smooth approximation of the distribution, you can differentiate to get $f'(a+x)f(a-x)-f'(a-x)f(a+x)=0$, or $\frac{f'(a+x)}{f(a+x)}=\frac{f'(a-x)}{f(a-x)}$.

For any two numbers  you can find an $a, x$ such that one equals $a+x$ and the other $a-x$, so for every number $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is the same, so $f'(x)=kf(x)$, so $f$ is exponential!"

Comment: It cannot be right (or, at any rate, cannot be complete), since you have not made any use of the energy condition.  Equivalently, you say that $f$ must be exponential, but not what it is an exponential function *of*.

Comment: @Buzz It slipped my mind copying it here and I've edited it in, but I'd have thought it's implicit what the function represents given the topic. What energy condition isn't used?

Comment: Aside from not knowing what $f$ is an exponential of, I'll also point out that shifting a function on $\mathbb{N}$ makes no sense because it's bounded below. Furthermore, the Boltzmann distribution extremizes the entropy, which is not the same as the number of states.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure; As I don't really get approximations made very well! But You  can do something like this:
$$\sum_r a_r=a$$
$$\sum a_rE_r=aE_0$$
$$\Gamma =\frac{a!}{a_1!a_2!\cdots }$$
$$\ln \Gamma =\ln a!-\sum_r \ln a_r!$$
Using the [stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), We have
$$\ln a_r!\approx a_r\ln a_r-a_r$$
$$\ln \Gamma =a\ln a-a-\sum_r a_r\ln a_r+\sum_r a_r=a\ln a-\sum_r a_r\ln a_r$$
To make the  above max subjected to conditions, You can use Lagrange multiplier method, But let's do this  with basics. At maximum we have
$$\delta \ln \Gamma=-\sum_r(\delta a_r+\ln a_r\delta a_r)=0$$
$$\sum_r \delta a_r=0$$
$$\sum E_r\delta a_r=0$$
The first two can be combined to give
$$\sum_r\ln a_r\delta a_r=0$$
with proper choice of $\alpha $ and $\beta $, We have
$$\sum_r(\ln a_r+\alpha +\beta E_r)\delta a_r=0$$
All the $\delta a_r$ are independent so that each coefficient must be zero separately! If we denote $\hat{a}_r$ for the value of $a_r$ which make $\Gamma $ max, then
$$\ln \hat{a}_r+\alpha +\beta E_r=0$$
$$\hat{a}_r\propto e^{-\beta E_r}$$
As required.